# Cordova build android --release can't join the server

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I'm using apache cord for my application. The problem is this: If I'm building an application with a command Cordova build android (without --release),  then everything connects successfully to the server. But if I collect applications for release, I can not connect to the server.

The application was published in Google Play. The assembly was successful. Maybe it's something to do with Google?

What can be the difference between the behavior of debug and relay applications?

```
cordova 8.0.0;
android-targetSdkVersion 23;
```

ok request
[image: ok request]

[image: screen 2]
[image: screen 3]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a different signing key for your release application, and need to add the signing key for your release application as authorized to your server.